# Getting URL using uid instead of id prismic io

Tags: angularjs, seo, content-management-system, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to get my URL using the uid instead of the id in integrating prismic io with angular but i get this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined
    at controllers.js:83
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
    at angular.js:11768
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
    at done (angular.js:8450)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
```

thats my controller :

```
.controller('DocumentCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Prismic', '$location', function($scope, $routeParams, Prismic, $location) {
        Prismic.document($routeParams.uid).then(function(document){
            if (document.slug === $routeParams.slug) {
                Prismic.ctx().then(function(ctx) {
                    $scope.document = document;
//      

        $scope.documentHtml = document.asHtml(ctx);
                console.log(document);
            })
        }
        else if (document.slugs.indexOf($routeParams.slug) >= 0) {
            $location.path('/document/'+document.uid+'/'+document.slug);
        }
        else {
            // Should display some kind of error; will just redirect to / for now
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });
}])
```

and here is my config route provider

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/:page?', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/document/:uid/:slug', {templateUrl: 'partials/document.html', controller: 'DocumentCtrl'});
//    $routeProvider.when('/document/:slug', {templateUrl: 'partials/document.html', controller: 'DocumentCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/search/:q*/:page?', {templateUrl: 'partials/search.html', controller: 'SearchCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

}]).
```

and it redirect to my documents here :

```
<ul id="list">
    <li ng-repeat=" document in documents.results">
        <a href="#/document/{{document.uid}}/{{document.slug}}">
            {{document.slug}}
        </a>


    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `document` is js predefined word. So, try giving another name instead of `document` and try once again.

Comment: The error message indicates that the `document`used in the `Prismic.document($routeParams.uid).then(function(document){` handler is `undefined`. Rename the `document`to something else since it's a JavaScript predefined 'variable'.

Comment: same issue i am getting

Comment: tried with another name?

Comment: yes same error you can clone my repo all what i am trying to do is to change the URL from putting the id in it to the type. https://github.com/heshamelmasry77/javascript-angular-starter . i wanna change this : http://127.0.0.1:52486/app/index.html#/document/WG90FCkAAMUrJCKv/tata .  to that : http://127.0.0.1:52486/app/index.html#/document/make/tata . thank you sai

Answer (score 0):

You can't query a document by UID this way with your project.
It's based on the module angularPrismicio (not official) which expose only a function document to query by id (https://github.com/awulder/angular-prismicio/blob/master/src/angularPrismicio.js#L288).
If you wanna keep this module you should just query with the function getByUID available on the api object in your context.
But i'd suggest you to remove this module and just use the official javascript-kit available here : https://github.com/prismicio/javascript-kit.
If you want a clean angular2 project, you can install it with the prismic command line tool. (*npm install prismic-cli* and then *prismic init*).